# Android SQLite convert time in onCreate method before passing it into object

Tags: java, android, methods

currently I have a TimePickerDialog where the user will select the time and the time will be passed into an object's parameters to create a row in my SQLite database. I want to store the time as 24 hour in the database, but I want it to be displayed to the user in 12 hour format. 
This is my TimePickerDialog code:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time = new 
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            if (hourOfDay < 10) {
                hourString = "0"
                        + hourOfDay;
            } else {
                hourString = String.valueOf(hourOfDay);
            }
            if (minute < 10) {
                minuteString = "0" + minute;
            } else {
                minuteString = String.valueOf(minute);
            }

            String twentyFourTime = hourString + ":" + minuteString;

            tvScheduleTime.setText(twentyFourTime);

        }
    };
```

Then on my onCreate method, I get the time from `tvScheduleTime` to save in the database

```
btnSaveSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // schedule items
                String scheduleName = etScheduleName.getText().toString();
                String scheduleDesc = etScheduleDesc.getText().toString();
                String scheduleDate = Day + " " + selectedMonth + " " + Year;
                String scheduleTime = tvScheduleTime.getText().toString();

                int routeID = 12345;

                Log.w("RESULTS", scheduleTime + scheduleDate);

                DatabaseScheduleHelper db = new DatabaseScheduleHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.addSchedule(new ObjectSchedule(scheduleTime, scheduleDate, scheduleName, scheduleDesc, routeID));


            }
        });
```

Essentially, my question is, I want the `scheduleTime` to be passed in the `ObjectSchedule` object to be in **24 hour format** and but for the text in `tvScheduleTime` to be in **12 hour format**. But how can I return the value of `twentyFourTime` from the TimePickerDialog listener to my onCreate method? Then from there I will be able to do all my conversions.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you just want a method to convert military time to normal time immediately when you get it (get it through DB or through OnTimeSetListener)? If so the method below should work (not tested).

`int hr =` grab from DB or from TimeListener

```
hr = convertToNormalTime(hr);

private int convertToNormalTime(int militaryTime){
    int hr = militaryTime;
    if(hr > 12){
        hr = militaryTime - 12; // to convert military to normal time always subtract by 12
    }
    return hr;
}
```